# Find a number $M$, such that $|x^3-4x^2+x+1| < M$ for all $1<x<3$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, optimization, absolute-value, maxima-minima

The question states that I cannot use calculus, so finding max/min of the function is not an accepted solution.

My attempt at solving the problem:

$|(x^3-4x^2) + (x+1)|$ $\le$ $|x^3-4x^2| + |x+1|$

$= |x^2||x-4| + |x+1|$

$ = x^2|x-4| + x+1$   (because 1 < x < 3 so x+1 will always be positive)

Plugging in 1 for x:

$ = 1(3) + 2$

$ = 5$

Plugging in 3 for x:

$ = 9(1) + 4 $

$ = 13 $

Therefore the value of M is 13 as there is no value in the interval from 1 < x <3 which is greater than the value outputted by 3.

Is this the right approach to the solution? When graphing the function I can see that 13 works as a value of M but there are other values that also work which are closer to the maximum of the function in that interval.

Comment: You are using that the function $x\mapsto |x-c|$ on some interval $[\alpha,\beta]$ is always maximized at either $\alpha$ or $\beta$. This is not difficult to prove, but it is missing in your proof. Another approach would be to use the triangle inequality for every term and then plug in $x=3$: $|x^3-4x^2+x+1| \leq |x|^3+4|x|^2+|x|+1$. This is easier, but yields an upper bound of $M=67$, which is clearly not optimal.

Comment: plug $$x=\frac{1}{3}(4+\sqrt{13})$$ in your term

Comment: @BrazilianCérebro: I think your answer 67 is the simplest. From the wording of the question it is clear that the intent is not to deal with maxima /minima but just find an upper bound of the given function.

Comment: Agree with Paramanand Singh. A typical step in $\epsilon-\delta$ proofs is to find some bound $M$. Nobody cares about the best possible bound, because finding one let's us complete the proof. Thus I'm inclined to go with the triangle inequality like Brazilian Cérebro. We might also go like
$$|x^3-4x^2+x+1|=|(x^3-4x^2+4x)+(1-3x)|\le |x|(x-2)^2+|3x-1|\le3\cdot1^2+8=11,$$
but what's the point :-)

Answer (score 0):

For all $1<x<3$ we have $$x^3-4x^2+x+1=x^3-4x^2+3x+1-2x=-x(3-x)(x-1)-2x+1<0.$$

Thus, we need to find the maximal value of $f(x)=-x^3+4x^2-x-1$ on $(1,3).$

We have $$f'(x)=-3x^2+8x-1,$$ which gives $$x_{max}=\frac{4+\sqrt{13}}{3}$$ and all $$M>f\left(\frac{4+\sqrt{13}}{3}\right)=\frac{13(5+2\sqrt{13})}{27}$$ is valid.

Comment: from where do you know that $x=x_{max}$ without using the second derivative?

Comment: $f'(x)>0$ for $1<x<x_{max}$ and $f'(x)<0$ for all $x_{max}<x<3$.

Comment: someone wrote me WITHOUT calculus, ok, you can use it and i not

Comment: We can use the AM-GM here, but it's very ugly, I think.

Comment: Without calculus. So without derivatives, I think.